# Django - Appending model parameter to url

Tags: python, django, url, models

Let's suppose I have this model

```
class Example(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And wanted that after the user fills the model to redirect to an url with the format

```
localhost/FirstName-Lastname
```

What would I need to write in the urls.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an url like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<first_name>\w+)-(?P<last_name>\w+)/$', views.your_view),
```

You can see docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Comment: Sorry, the first one is including `-` (dash)